# How can I deploy my web app with a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, web-deployment

I'me trying to deploy a built vue.js on a node.js server with only ftp.

So my build app is like this :

```
dist/
- js/
- css/
- index.html
```

I have tried to build package.json and server.js file.

package.json :

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    }
  }
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express(),
      port = 80;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on the port::${port}`);
});
```

And on my ftp files are like this :

```
default/
 - dist/
 - node_modules/
 - server.js
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
```

I do not have ssh access to the server. Do someone have any idea on how to deploy my app.

Comment: Something has to execute the node process and maintain it's up time. If you have no access to your server to execute scripts, this isn't possible. Without more information about the hosting provider, there isn't much we can do to help here.

Comment: Like nodemon maybe ?

Comment: Sure, nodemon is fine.

Comment: I will try to contact my provider to have a little ssh access. And except that my conf files are good ?

Comment: you have to install node in your server or user docker .. then use something like *pm2* to keep your node app working continuously,